# Trying to launch Xamarin Forms Content Page from Xamarin Android Native app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, auth0

New to Xamarin, C#, and Auth0.

Since Auth0 doesn't support Xamarin Forms, but only Xamarin Native, I have to create a Xamarin Native Android app to perform login. After the login I want to switch to my Xamarin Forms so that I can share the rest of the app with the IOS version.

Here is my activity_sign_in.xml (the xml of the main page).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/content_sign_in" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the main parts of my SignInActivity.cs

```
public class SignInActivity : FragmentActivity
{

    private static Context      _context;
    public static Context Context { get => _context; }
    public static string FolderPath { get; private set; }

    public static SignInActivity Instance;

    private Auth0Client         auth0Client;
    private UserTokens          userTokens;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Instance = this;
        Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        _context = Context;
        auth0Client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
        {
            Domain = GetString(Resource.String.auth0_domain),
            ClientId = GetString(Resource.String.auth0_client_id),
            Scope = "openid profile email"
        }, this);

        FetchExistingToken();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_sign_in);

        if (userTokens == null)
        {
            CreateAuthentication();
        }
        else
        {
            LoadChooseLocation();
        }

        FolderPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        Auth0.OidcClient.ActivityMediator.Instance.Send(intent.DataString);
        Console.WriteLine("SignIn intent fired:" + intent);
    }
}
```

The general flow of this is like this...The app starts and calls FetchExistingTokens() to load a token from the previous login. If there was one it uses that token. If not, it allows the user to login.

User clicks the Login button and it leaves the current app and launches a browser window that allows the user to connect to auth0. When connected, auth0, fires an Intent into my app so that I can return it to them and verify that the sign in came from my app.

If the tokens are found or, at the end of the auth0 signin process, the activity calls LoadChosenLocations(). I've found several ways to do this, but here's the one I'm currently using.

```
    private void LoadChooseLocation()
    {
        prepareForms();
        //INavService navService = ApplicationSettings.Current.Kernel.Get<INavService>() as XamarinFormsNavService;
        //Console.WriteLine("Navigating with:" + navService);
        //navService.NavigateTo<ChooseLocationViewModel>();

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChooseLocationActivity));
        //StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void prepareForms()
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment chooseLocationPage = new ChooseLocationPage().CreateSupportFragment(this);
        SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, chooseLocationPage)
            .Commit();
    }
```

The hope is, at the end of all of this, it will redirect to ChooseLocationPage which is a Xamarin Forms ContentPage.

Everything appears to be working, but after the Auth0 login, it returns to the login page and displays nothing else. There are no errors in the log.

I have searched everywhere and cobbled this code together from various pages and stackoverflow entries, but can't seem to unstick myself.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of recreating the startup procedure, why not use a Form-based app to start with and use a dependency service to invoke "native" auth0 process. i.e. Forms -> Auth0 (via dependency service call) / return "tokens" via dependency method return -> Forms

Comment: Switching in and out of Forms and Native is not a good idea... :/

Comment: @SushiHangover Because the intent doesn't appear to work right in Xamarin Forms. Believe me, I started with that.

Comment: @tommy99 it wasn't my first plan, but it works with Auth0 and according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms

Comment: @Thom Not sure what you mean by that, the Auth0 intent activity AND the Form's activity should be SingleTop based to insure that new ones are not created on the Activity stack.